# MySQL select from multiple records only records with first and last date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table [HC_RSPI_data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1331f/17):

```
| RADIO_TYPE |   HOP | TOWARDS | RSPI |       TP_NAME |          DATE_TIME_END | TIME_LENGTH | RLTM_min | RLTM_max |
|------------|-------|---------|------|---------------|------------------------|-------------|----------|----------|
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       70 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 09 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
```

And i want to get the records with the first and last day like:

```
| RADIO_TYPE |   HOP | TOWARDS | RSPI |       TP_NAME |          DATE_TIME_END | TIME_LENGTH | RLTM_min | RLTM_max |
|------------|-------|---------|------|---------------|------------------------|-------------|----------|----------|
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       65 |       37 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 1 Radio 1 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       70 |       37 |

| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 08 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
| FlexiMetro | H3376 | RAPSANI | RSPI | ODU 2 Radio 2 | June, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       86400 |       74 |       47 |
```

OR

One record with  2 fileds Start date and End date like:
`min(DATE_TIME_END)` as Start date and  `max(DATE_TIME_END)` as End date

How can i achieve this?
I was trying something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT rssi.* 
FROM HC_RSPI_data as rssi
INNER JOIN HC_RSPI_data as j
on  rssi.RADIO_TYPE     =   j.RADIO_TYPE     
and rssi.HOP            =   j.HOP            
and rssi.TOWARDS        =   j.TOWARDS        
and rssi.RSPI           =   j.RSPI           
and rssi.TP_NAME        =   j.TP_NAME
and rssi.DATE_TIME_END = j.DATE_TIME_END or j.DATE_TIME_END = DATE_ADD(rssi.DATE_TIME_END, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "OR One record with 2 fileds Start date and End date"?  Which format do you want?  Two rows, one for the start and end, or one row, with both values?

Comment: And what after your query execution?

Comment: Whatever is easier.Better one row for start and one for date or one record with start and end both are ok.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to aggregate the data and use a `join` to get the appropriate values:

```
SELECT rssi.* 
FROM HC_RSPI_data rssi INNER JOIN
     (SELECT RADIO_TYPE, HOP, TOWARDS, RSPI, TP_NAME,
             MIN(DATE_TIME) as mindt, MAX(DATE_TIME) maxdt
      FROM HC_RSPI_data
      GROUP BY RADIO_TYPE, HOP, TOWARDS, RSPI, TP_NAME
     ) j
     ON  rssi.RADIO_TYPE     =   j.RADIO_TYPE and
         rssi.HOP            =   j.HOP and
         rssi.TOWARDS        =   j.TOWARDS and       
         rssi.RSPI           =   j.RSPI and    
         rssi.TP_NAME        =   j.TP_NAME
         rssi.DATE_TIME in (j.mindt, j.maxdt);
```

Comment: There are some mistakes but i got the idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To get one row with start and end Date:

```
SELECT rssi.RADIO_TYPE, rssi.HOP, rssi.TOWARDS, rssi.RSPI, rssi.TP_NAME,
 MIN(rssi.DATE_TIME_END) as mindt, MAX(rssi.DATE_TIME_END) as maxdt
 FROM HC_RSPI_data as rssi 
 GROUP BY rssi.RADIO_TYPE, rssi.HOP, rssi.TOWARDS, rssi.RSPI, rssi.TP_NAME
```